# Call to undefined function db_query

Tags: php, database, drupal-7

I have tried to configure a module that  can get data from the database. I have used `db_query` to do this and every time I run the module I get the error:

```
Call to undefined function db_query.
```

I have been searching for months to find the answer to this and all I can find is that I need to bootstrap the page.

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. $SERVER["REDIRECT_COMMUNITY_SUBSITE"]);
// Bootstrap Drupal up through the database phase.
require_once (DRUPAL_ROOT. '/includes/bootstrap.inc');
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

However I am fairly sure I don't need to do this in a `.module` file but this seems to be the only thing that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you use your .module file?

You can follow this tutorial to properly create a module:

[Creating modules - a tutorial: Drupal 7.x](https://www.drupal.org/node/1074360)

Comment: Thanks @T-34
That, along with Buildamodule.com, are the guides I used to help me create this module.
I know that in that tutorial they use db_select and I am using db_query but that shouldnt make a difference should it?

Also, What do you mean "How do you use your .module file?"
I tried separating everything out into different .inc files and that didn't work so now everything is in the .module file

Answer (score 0):

If your Drupal is bootstrapped properly, it's probably a caching glitch.

Try restarting your caches such as memcached.

When using module or drush, you don't need to worry about bootstrapping Drupal, since it should be done automatically.

Using `drush` command you can invoke any PHP code with already Drupal bootstrap, e.g.

```
drush ev "some_function();"
drush scr file.php
```

To bootstrap Drupal manually from external code, you just need:

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

then execute any code you need.